# React on key up execute setTimeout only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to run something when the user finishes typing, when the timer finishes basically. Timer is being reset when user is typing but once time is over, it will run the function for as many times as the user typed

```
export default function SearchMovie() {
    var keyUpTimer = 0;
    const keyUpTimerDelay = 2000;


    const handleOnKeyUp = (event) => {
        clearTimeout(keyUpTimer);
        keyUpTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    
            console.log(input);
        }, keyUpTimerDelay);
    };


    return (
        <div className="search-container">
            <input
                type="text"
                className="input-text"
                onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                onKeyUp={handleOnKeyUp}
                placeholder="Type a movie to search..."
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because React will call your function every render, every time your component renders, a new `keyUpTimer` variable with the value of `0` is created, so you are never really clearing the old timer. In order to maintain the same timer variable for every render, you should use a [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

```js
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

export default function SearchMovie() {
    var keyUpTimer = useRef(null); // keyUpTimer will be a Ref object
    const keyUpTimerDelay = 2000;


    const handleOnKeyUp = (event) => {
        clearTimeout(keyUpTimer.current); // use `current` to access the value
        // the `current` property is mutable and changing it will not cause a rerender
        keyUpTimer.current = setTimeout(() => {
    
            console.log(input);
        }, keyUpTimerDelay);
    };


    return (
        <div className="search-container">
            <input
                type="text"
                className="input-text"
                onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                onKeyUp={handleOnKeyUp}
                placeholder="Type a movie to search..."
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I didn't know about `current` nor references. However i did try to cancel the timer again on a `onKeyDown` and that seemed to work, but it felt like a hack

Comment: Yea the onKeyDown could work, to get the next keypress, but it is a bit of a hack.  The "React" way would be to use a Ref for the timer. The real issue at play here is that each call to your function creates a new execution context with its own variables. The second render won't see the same `keyUpTimer` variable as the first, so when it creates and attaches the `handleOnKeyUp` function, it's actually a _new_ function looking at the _new_ `keyUpTimer` variable that was just created.